# How do you change the development target?

Tags: xcode, ios, deployment, target

I'm wondering how to change the deployment target in Xcode 3.2.3

Comment: What do you want to change, exactly? Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

Open target info, go to *Build* tab ant there you'll find your option. Check out following image for details: http://oi52.tinypic.com/5p52fn.jpg